# Vim: Dynamically loading a syntax?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to load a syntax file depending of the contents of a variable? Something like this:

```
syntax include @CSYN "syntax/" + b:language + ".vim"
syntax region cSnip start="<" end=">" keepend contains=@CSYN
```

Comment: what's wrong with `set syntax=ON`?  or you can later `set syntax=xxxx`. does it answer your question?

Comment: You can also use Vim comment `# vi: syn=blabla`.

Comment: I am using the loaded syntax for syntax highlighting embedded expressions, not the whole file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:execute`, and the string concatenation in Vimscript is with `.` not `+` (for more complex stuff, prefer `printf()`):

```
:execute 'syntax include @CSYN syntax/' . b:language . '.vim'
```